# How to use .cts extension with esm typescript project?

Tags: typescript, es6-modules

I'm struggling to get Typescript to work with a mix of ES and commonjs modules in the same code. Any help on misconfiguration or explanation on why this won't work would be greatly appreciated. I continue to get the following error:

> <omitted>/typescript-esm/esm-with-cts/src/commonjs.cts:1
> import path from 'node:path';
> ^^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Here is a sample codebase I've tried to use:

https://github.com/shawnsparks/typescript-esm/tree/main/esm-with-cts

Comment: Well `import path from 'node:path'` is not commonjs?!

Comment: But it is common typescript when using commonjs because you haven't configured anything for esm

Comment: @Bergi are you saying you can no longer use standard TypeScript import syntax when using a .cts extension? Isn't the .cts extension supposed to denote this should follow Typescript for commonjs convention which is how Typescript has worked before any support for ESM was added?

Comment: I might remember this wrong, but wasn't the old TypeScript syntax [`import path = require('path')`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require)?

Comment: "*because you haven't configured anything for esm*" - but [you have](https://github.com/shawnsparks/typescript-esm/blob/6328c8d22b5e48b1dce16fecf2aed1f1ab82a3e7/esm-with-cts/tsconfig.json#L3), by specifying `"module": "ES2022",` in your config

Comment: *"because you haven't configured anything for esm"* - I didn't state that well. I meant you can use `import path from 'node:path'` when you have `"module": "commonjs"` and `"moduleResolution": "node"` in the tsconfig.json. I'd be surprised to find it can no longer be used when relying on a .cts extension.